# Search for all paths to the value in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have a complex JavaScript object given below.

An example object:

```
var object= {
    "name": "tfifkhul",
    "id": "262761",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "rthrth",
            "id": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "test",
                    "id": "262762",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "rthsrth",
            "id": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "test",
                    "id": "262762",
                    "children": []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "rthrthhrth",
            "id": 0,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "test",
                    "id": "262762",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "rtjrtj",
                            "id": 0,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "fwefwefwef",
                                    "id": "262768",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "hsrtjrtdjrtj",
                            "id": 0,
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "we4yhesrhy",
                                    "id": "262764",
                                    "children": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "lol",
                            "id": "262763",
                            "children": [
                                {
                                    "name": "fwefwefwef",
                                    "id": "262768",
                                    "children": [
                                        {
                                            "name": "87ok78",
                                            "id": "262765",
                                            "children": [
                                                {
                                                    "name": "78o78",
                                                    "id": 0,
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "we4yhesrhy",
                                                            "id": "262764",
                                                            "children": [
                                                                {
                                                                    "name": "test1",
                                                                    "id": 0,
                                                                    "children": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "name": "",
                                                                            "id": "262766",
                                                                            "children": []
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                },
                                                                {
                                                                    "name": "test2",
                                                                    "id": 0,
                                                                    "children": [
                                                                        {
                                                                            "name": "",
                                                                            "id": "262766",
                                                                            "children": []
                                                                        }
                                                                    ]
                                                                }
                                                            ]
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "7o78o76o8",
                                                    "id": 0,
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "",
                                                            "id": "262766",
                                                            "children": []
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "name": "ko",
                                                    "id": 0,
                                                    "children": [
                                                        {
                                                            "name": "",
                                                            "id": "262767",
                                                            "children": []
                                                        }
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

I need to create a function to search for all matching values for key "id" with given value.

So far I have created one recursive function:

```
function searchOccurances(theObject, value,path) {
        var result = null;
        if(theObject instanceof Array) {
            for(var i = 0; i < theObject.length; i++) {

                result = searchOccurances(theObject[i],value,path+","+i);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for(prop in theObject) {

                if(prop == 'id') {
                    if(theObject[prop] == value) {
                        keyOccurances.push(path);
                    }
                }
                if((theObject[prop] instanceof Array) || (theObject[prop] instanceof Object))
                {
                    if((theObject[prop].length!=undefined)&&(theObject[prop].length!=0))
                    {
                        result = searchOccurances(theObject[prop],value,path+","+prop);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
keyOccurances=[];
searchOccurances(object,262762,'');
console.log(keyOccurances);
//Output
[",children,0,children,0", ",children,1,children,0", ",children,2,children,0"] -- correct

keyOccurances=[];
searchOccurances(object,262768,'');
console.log(keyOccurances);

//Output 
[",children,1,children,0,children,1,children,0", ",children,1,children,0,children,2,children,0"] --wrong
```

The function returns array of comma separated paths of matched value but doesn't seems to be getting right results. For the first call with value '262762' gives corrects path list but for value '262768' gives incorrect path list.

Kindly help.

Comment: do you still need the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest to provide a better test object. Would you really have so many children with 'id = 0' in a real use case? Would you have 2 children with the same ID at all? That makes things pretty hard to debug.

Below is an example function that should work as expected.

```
function search(object, value) {
  var res = [], searchPath;

  (searchPath = function(children, path) {
    var n, newPath;

    for(n in children) {
      if(typeof children[n].id !== 'undefined' && parseInt(children[n].id, 10) === value) {
        res.push(path);
      }
      newPath = path.slice();
      newPath.push(children[n].id);
      searchPath(children[n].children, newPath);
    }
  })([ object ], []);

  return res;
}

console.log(search(object, 262762));
console.log(search(object, 262768));
```

Output:

```
[["262761", 0], ["262761", 0], ["262761", 0]]
[["262761", 0, "262762", 0], ["262761", 0, "262762", "262763"]]
```

The above code is not (yet) bullet-proof but hopefully is it short enough to be easily understandable.

Comment: Because of the problems with `parseInt` I recommend coercing with the unary `+` operator or supplying the radix to `parseInt`: `parseInt(children[n].id, 10);`

Comment: Oh, you're right. I still forget this one from time to time. Fixed.

Comment: Don't sweat it, We all do :)

Comment: the test object  is the least complex structure that have posted. The original data is having much more deeper hierarchy and the data with same id can appear .

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you're looking for all paths where a specific id is present. I'd recommend not reinventing the wheel here and using an existing library. We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for most of our data processing now. It's powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you'd answer your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const findKeys = (haystack, id) => objectScan(['**'], {
  joined: true,
  filterFn: ({ value }) => value.id === id
})(haystack);

const object = { name: 'tfifkhul', id: '262761', children: [{ name: 'rthrth', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'test', id: '262762', children: [] }] }, { name: 'rthsrth', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'test', id: '262762', children: [] }] }, { name: 'rthrthhrth', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'test', id: '262762', children: [{ name: 'rtjrtj', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'fwefwefwef', id: '262768', children: [] }] }, { name: 'hsrtjrtdjrtj', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'we4yhesrhy', id: '262764', children: [] }] }, { name: 'lol', id: '262763', children: [{ name: 'fwefwefwef', id: '262768', children: [{ name: '87ok78', id: '262765', children: [{ name: '78o78', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'we4yhesrhy', id: '262764', children: [{ name: 'test1', id: 0, children: [{ name: '', id: '262766', children: [] }] }, { name: 'test2', id: 0, children: [{ name: '', id: '262766', children: [] }] }] }] }, { name: '7o78o76o8', id: 0, children: [{ name: '', id: '262766', children: [] }] }, { name: 'ko', id: 0, children: [{ name: '', id: '262767', children: [] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] };

console.log(findKeys(object, '262762'));
/* =>
 [ 'children[2].children[0]',
   'children[1].children[0]',
   'children[0].children[0]' ]
*/
console.log(findKeys(object, '262768'));
/* =>
 [ 'children[2].children[0].children[2].children[0]',
   'children[2].children[0].children[0].children[0]' ]
*/
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)

---

Edit: The accepted answer didn't make much sense to me (based on the question), but here is how you could generate the same output

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const findIdPath = (haystack, id) => objectScan(['**'], {
  reverse: false,
  filterFn: ({ value, parents, context }) => {
    if (value.id === id) {
      context.push(parents.filter((p) => 'id' in p).map((p) => p.id).reverse());
    }
  }
})(haystack, []);

const object = { name: 'tfifkhul', id: '262761', children: [{ name: 'rthrth', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'test', id: '262762', children: [] }] }, { name: 'rthsrth', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'test', id: '262762', children: [] }] }, { name: 'rthrthhrth', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'test', id: '262762', children: [{ name: 'rtjrtj', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'fwefwefwef', id: '262768', children: [] }] }, { name: 'hsrtjrtdjrtj', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'we4yhesrhy', id: '262764', children: [] }] }, { name: 'lol', id: '262763', children: [{ name: 'fwefwefwef', id: '262768', children: [{ name: '87ok78', id: '262765', children: [{ name: '78o78', id: 0, children: [{ name: 'we4yhesrhy', id: '262764', children: [{ name: 'test1', id: 0, children: [{ name: '', id: '262766', children: [] }] }, { name: 'test2', id: 0, children: [{ name: '', id: '262766', children: [] }] }] }] }, { name: '7o78o76o8', id: 0, children: [{ name: '', id: '262766', children: [] }] }, { name: 'ko', id: 0, children: [{ name: '', id: '262767', children: [] }] }] }] }] }] }] }] };

console.log(findIdPath(object, '262762'));
// => [ [ '262761', 0 ], [ '262761', 0 ], [ '262761', 0 ] ]
console.log(findIdPath(object, '262768'));
// => [ [ '262761', 0, '262762', 0 ], [ '262761', 0, '262762', '262763' ] ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)